# How do I wrap text in a pre tag for Internet explorer?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, whitespace, word-wrap

I am using following code to wrap the `<PRE>` region in HTML:

```
 <PRE style = "white-space: pre-wrap;
               white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
               white-space: -pre-wrap;
               white-space: -o-pre-wrap;
               word-wrap: break-word;">
```

It is working fine on chrome and Mozilla but the same is not working for IE.
I am using IE9.

Please tell me if any other property needs to be set to wrap the text in IE?

Comment: what is your `DOCTYPE`?

Comment: The doctype is HTML.

Comment: have you specified an xml namespace? (is there an `xmlns` attribute in your `<html>` tag?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For IE 6 and 7 you need to wrap your text with a  tag and give it a white-space property. Since you already have a  tag wrapped around your text and you have a class for it, just add the white-space property to your 
do something like this

```css
#pre-wrap {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
    <p id="pre-wrap">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
       consectetuer    adipiscing   elit     sed   diam   nonummy   
    
    
    nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet
    </p>
```

Comment: you could use <pre> instead of <p>

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I tried the following `<span>white-space: pre-wrap;</span>
<PRE class='abc' id= "pre-wrap" style = "white-space: pre-wrap;white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;white-space: -pre-wrap;white-space: -o-pre-wrap;word-wrap: break-word;">` Can you please edit the above code which I wrote and add the property you suggested as it is directly printing span contents on the screen

Comment: By using your edited code I am getting following output `#pre-wrap { white-space: pre-wrap; } 
The Suggested Overall Rating is calculated by the application. Enter this value as your Overall Rating if you agree with the calculated rating.` all text in one line.                   The expected                    output is                                                                 The Suggested Overall Rating is calculated by the application. 
Enter this value as your Overall Rating if you agree with the
calculated rating.